ROS2-humble-xacro-robot using luanch.py with spawn_entitiy.py cannot connect with gazebo
I made a robot using xacro and .STL model in ROS2-humble. I can easily see my robot in Rviz2 with launch file. But when I try to see it in gazebo. Something wrong happens.
This is my launch file, which name is gazebo.launch.py:
from ament_index_python.packages import get_package_share_directory
from launch import LaunchDescription, launch_description_sources, actions
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, ExecuteProcess, SetEnvironmentVariable
from launch.substitutions import Command
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.parameter_descriptions import ParameterValue


def generate_launch_description():
    package_name = 'robot_description'
    urdf_path=os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'urdf', 'robot_arm.urdf.xacro'
        )
    world_path=os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory(package_name), 'worlds', 'empty_world.sdf'
        )
    
    ld= LaunchDescription()
    robot_state_publisher_node = Node(
        package='robot_state_publisher',
        executable='robot_state_publisher',
        parameters=[{'robot_description': Command(['xacro ',urdf_path])}],
        output='screen',
    )

    launch_gazebo =actions.IncludeLaunchDescription(
            launch_description_sources.PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(
                os.path.join('/opt/ros/humble/share/gazebo_ros/launch/', 
                         'gazebo.launch.py')),
                launch_arguments={
                    'world': world_path,}.items()
    )
    spawmer_node = Node(
        package="gazebo_ros",
        executable="spawn_entity.py",
        arguments=["-topic", "/robot_description", "-entity", "robot"],
        output="screen",
    )
    rviz_node = Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen',)
    

    ld.add_action(robot_state_publisher_node)
    ld.add_action(launch_gazebo)
    ld.add_action(spawmer_node)
    ld.add_action(rviz_node)
    return ld

And I use the command ros2 launch robot_description gazebo.launch.py
cmd shows:
[INFO] [robot_state_publisher-1]: process started with pid [9089]
[INFO] [gzserver-2]: process started with pid [9091]
[INFO] [gzclient-3]: process started with pid [9093]
[INFO] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process started with pid [9095]
[INFO] [rviz2-5]: process started with pid [9097]
[rviz2-5] Warning: Ignoring XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland on Gnome. Use QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland to run on Wayland anyway.
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1730262495.281978977] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment base_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1730262495.282105714] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment dummy_link
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1730262495.282116416] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link1
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1730262495.282120624] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link2
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1730262495.282124377] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link3
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1730262495.282127929] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link4
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1730262495.282131345] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link5
[robot_state_publisher-1] [INFO] [1730262495.282134831] [robot_state_publisher]: got segment link6
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730262495.512661626] [spawn_entity]: Spawn Entity started
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730262495.513220168] [spawn_entity]: Loading entity published on topic /robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] /opt/ros/humble/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/rclpy/qos.py:307: UserWarning: DurabilityPolicy.RMW_QOS_POLICY_DURABILITY_TRANSIENT_LOCAL is deprecated. Use DurabilityPolicy.TRANSIENT_LOCAL instead.
[spawn_entity.py-4]   warnings.warn(
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730262495.520352653] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for entity xml on /robot_description
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730262495.533821857] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity, timeout = 30
[spawn_entity.py-4] [INFO] [1730262495.534165421] [spawn_entity]: Waiting for service /spawn_entity

And nothing happens. Gazebo did not open either. Until it shows:
[spawn_entity.py-4] [ERROR] [1730267109.147747022] [spawn_entity]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
[ERROR] [spawn_entity.py-4]: process has died [pid 10676, exit code 1, cmd '/opt/ros/humble/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_entity.py -topic /robot_description -entity robot --ros-args'].

I printed ros2 service list.
It showed
/gazebo/describe_parameters
/gazebo/get_parameter_types
/gazebo/get_parameters
/gazebo/list_parameters
/gazebo/set_parameters
/gazebo/set_parameters_atomically
/robot_state_publisher/describe_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameter_types
/robot_state_publisher/get_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/list_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters
/robot_state_publisher/set_parameters_atomically
/rviz2/describe_parameters
/rviz2/get_parameter_types
/rviz2/get_parameters
/rviz2/list_parameters
/rviz2/set_parameters
/rviz2/set_parameters_atomically
/spawn_entity
/spawn_entity/describe_parameters
/spawn_entity/get_parameter_types
/spawn_entity/get_parameters
/spawn_entity/list_parameters
/spawn_entity/set_parameters
/spawn_entity/set_parameters_atomically

which means I had/spawn_entitynode. But why can't gazebo be opened?
I really need help!!!!!!!!
Thanks

All right I solve the problem using adding source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.bash
andPATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/gazebo in ~/.bashrc.But here comes another question. Gazebo just quit and Rivz2 shows that the links except base_link has no transform.  
How can I solve it?

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
